# Обновление значения переменной

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Дана переменная с числовым значением. Как можно реагировать на ее изменение при помощи JQuery/AJAX? Например, если значение переменной изменилось, то выполняется определенный кусок кода?

Comment: @RomanAnanev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1**

Когда страница загрузилась, активируется Ваш код и начинает выполнять операции, и внутри него Вы ловите изменения переменных подобным образом:

```
 if(переменная==1){
  //Кусок кода
 }
```

**Вариант 2**

Когда страница загрузилась и юзер начал двигать мышью или нажал на что-нибудь, активируется код, который сверяет данные. Т.е. реакция на события.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  //Это устанавливается, когда страница загрузилась.
  var s = 0;
  $( "button" ).click(function() {
     if(s==0){
     //Один участок кода при s==0, наступает только когда юзер нажал на кнопку
     s++; // Увеличиваем нашу переменную на 1
     } else {
     //Другой при s==1 при повторном нажатии на кнопку.
     s--; //Уменьшаем нашу переменную 1
     }
  });
 });
```